# Serializing Charfields to Point GeoDjango

Tags: python, geojson, geodjango, django

I have two CharField in my model (longitude and latitude), I want serialize them with GeoJSON serializer and serve as API so I can use on Leaflet to show points on map, but GeoJSON serializer only have geometry_field (it takes only one argument). How can I solve this?

models.py

```
class ParkingAreas(models.Model):
    park_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    park_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    park_capacity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    working_hours = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    county_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
       test = serialize('geojson', ParkingAreas.objects.all(),
                geometry_field='longitude', 'latitude',
                fields=('park_name',))
       print(test)
       return HttpResponse('ok')
```

Comment: This the format you need to end up with `{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-86.1865235,39.6960606]}`  That's [lon, lat] or [x, y] for the coordinate order.

Comment: Hello friend, how did you manage to solve this kind of problem? I hope you can share your solution, I'm going through the same problem, thank you.